# Rake resque:workers command forks infinite processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

I have a rails project, which uses resque workers, with a Gemfile like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'rest-open-uri'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'therubyracer' # If using Ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'

gem 'devise'

gem 'net-http-digest_auth', '1.2.1'

gem "resque", :require => "resque/server"

gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'kaminari'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

After I do a `bundle install` and try to start some resque workers with the command `rake resque:work QUEUE=checker_queue` or `bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=checker_queue` my machine stops responding (to anything). When I observe the system with `htop` I see that rake creates new processes until both memory and swap space of the machine is full (at which point machine becomes unresponsive).

**Any ideas regardind the cause of this strange behaviour?**

Redis version:

```
# redis-server -v
Redis server version 2.2.12 (00000000:0)
```

Ruby version:

```
# ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.15)
      actionpack (= 3.2.15)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (3.2.15)
      activemodel (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.15)
      activemodel (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.15)
      activemodel (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
    activesupport (3.2.15)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    carrierwave (0.9.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    devise (3.1.1)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.5)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    less (2.4.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (2.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.4.0)
    less-rails-bootstrap (3.0.4)
      less-rails (~> 2.4.2)
    libv8 (3.16.14.3)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25)
    mono_logger (1.1.0)
    multi_json (1.8.2)
    net-http-digest_auth (1.2.1)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-protection (1.5.1)
      rack
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.15)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.15)
      actionpack (= 3.2.15)
      activerecord (= 3.2.15)
      activeresource (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.15)
    railties (3.2.15)
      actionpack (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.0.5)
    redis-namespace (1.3.2)
      redis (~> 3.0.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    resque (1.25.1)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.2)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    rest-open-uri (1.0.0)
    sass (3.2.12)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sinatra (1.4.4)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.8)
    therubyracer (0.12.0)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  devise
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  less-rails-bootstrap
  net-http-digest_auth (= 1.2.1)
  rails (= 3.2.15)
  resque
  rest-open-uri
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  therubyracer
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a bug in app code that schedules resque jobs or maybe there are lots of jobs pending or maybe the problem lies in the task itself. In any case also try to inspect resque status:

```
   Resque.info
   Resque.size :medium
```

Maybe it will help identify the problem

Comment: The app is not even started at this point yet, all I do is `bundle install` and start worker... Also the queue is empty as this is the first run on this machine.

Comment: Well then it's probably a bug. Try using different resque version or otherwise changing other configuration parameters, ruby version etc. There some open issues with resque eating up 100% cpu like https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/issues/205 and https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/723